# Rotate a rectangle using ShapeRenderer in libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx

How come my `rect` does not rotate during `draw()`?

When I enable `box2d` debug I see the actual box2d object rotating correctly but the actual rendered shape does not rotate ..

[image: screenshot]

```
Tween.to(getPlayer(), ShapeAccessor.ANGLE, 0.7f)
    .target(0.4f)
    .ease(Elastic.OUT)
    .repeatYoyo(0, 0)
    .start(getLevel().getTweenManager());
```

`Player` has the following `draw()` method ..

```
public void draw(ShapeRenderer sRenderer, Vector2 pos) {

    sRenderer.begin(ShapeType.Filled);
    sRenderer.setColor(getColor().r, getColor().g, getColor().b, getColor().a);
    sRenderer.identity();
    sRenderer.rotate(0, 0, 1, getAngle());
    sRenderer.translate(pos.x - getWidth(), pos.y - getHeight(), 0);
    sRenderer.rect(0, 0, getWidth() * 2, getHeight() * 2);
    sRenderer.end();        
}
```

Heres my `TweenAccessor` ..

```
public class ShapeAccessor implements TweenAccessor<Shape> {

    public static final int ANGLE = 5;

    public int getValues(Shape target, int tweenType, float[] returnValues) {

        switch (tweenType) {

            case ANGLE: // animate object by rotation

                returnValues[0] = ((Shape) target).getBody().getAngle();
                return 1;

            default: 
                assert false; 
                return -1;
        }
    }

    public void setValues(Shape target, int tweenType, float[] newValues) {

        switch (tweenType) {

            case ANGLE: // animate object by rotation

                ((Shape) target).getBody().setTransform(
                        ((Shape) target).getBody().getPosition(),
                        newValues[0]);
                break;

            default: 
                assert false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't know about the tween stuff but your `draw` method looks good. rectangle should be rotating `if (getAngle() % 360 != 0)`. So checked that first. Have you changed axis somewhere?

Comment: @MennoGouw what do you mean about the axis? dont think ive altered axis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed to scale angle up by `60` and modify the `.rect` coordinates ..

```
sRenderer.begin(ShapeType.Filled);
sRenderer.setColor(getColor().r, getColor().g, getColor().b, getColor().a);
sRenderer.identity();
sRenderer.translate(pos.x, pos.y, 0);
sRenderer.rotate(0, 0, 1, getBody().getAngle() * 60.0f);
sRenderer.rect(-getWidth(), -getHeight(), getWidth() * 2, getHeight() * 2);
sRenderer.end();
```